# Ditching ActiveRecord and NHibernate -- how to rearchitect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, architecture, castle-activerecord

I have an MVC3 NHibernate/ActiveRecord project. The project is going okay, and I'm getting a bit of use out of my model objects (mostly one giant hierarchy of three or four classes).

My application is analytics based; I store hierarchial data, and later slice it up, display it in graphs, etc. so the actual relationship is not that complicated.

So far, I haven't benefited much from ORM; it makes querying easy (ActiveRecord), but I frequently need less information than full objects, and I need to write "hard" queries through complex and multiple selects and iterations over collections -- raw SQL would be much faster and cleaner.

So I'm thinking about ditching ORM in this case, and going back to raw SQL. But I'm not sure how to rearchitect my solution. How should I handle the database tier?

- Should I still have one class per model, with static methods to query for objects? Or should I have one class representing the DB?
- Should I write my own layer under ActiveRecord (or my own ActiveRecord-like implementation) to keep the existing code more or less sound?
- Should I combine ORM methods (like Save/Delete) into my model classes or not?
- Should I change my table structure (one table per class with all of the fields)?

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm trying to figure out the best architecture and design to go with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many, including myself, think the ActiveRecord pattern is an anti-pattern mainly because it breaks the SRP and doesn't allow POCO objects (tightly coupling your domain to a particular ORM).

In saying that, you can't beat an ORM for simple CRUD stuff, so I would keep some kind of ORM around for that kind of work. Just re-architect your application to use POCO objects and some kind or repository pattern with your ORM implementation specifics in another project.

As for your "hard" queries, I would consider creating one class per view using a tiny ORM (like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), or [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive)), to query the objects with your own raw sql.

Comment: +1 decent answer. I think you're right; I can't get away from ORM entirely. Thanks for the great links. Can you recommend Dapper vs. PetaPoco? They all seem so similar and I've never used any of them.

Comment: I can't really recommend one over the other because I only have (a little) experience with Dapper. I found Dapper to be great, and it's made by the good people here at stackoverflow, so I'd give that a nudge.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks for your answer.